# How to receive socket via private channel in laravel broadcasting using laravel-echo-server

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, socket.io

Im using Laravel 5.7 with redis/ laravel-echo-server for broadcasting.
Front-end is vuejs
currently at public channel broadcasting is working as well.
but at private channel not working receiving socket at front-end

Follow is my codebase.

This code part is route code for authentication

```
Broadcast::channel('notification-{id}', function ($user, $id) {
    return (int) $user->id === (int) $id;
});
```

This is Event part

```
class NotificationEvent implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public $user;
    public function __construct(User $user)
    {
        //
        $this->user = $user;

    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PrivateChannel('notification-' . $this->user->id);
    }

    public function broadcastWith()
    {
        return ['data' => 'this is message'];
    }

}
```

This is front-end code

```
//bootstrap.js
 window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: "socket.io",
    host: window.location.hostname + ":6001"
 });
```

// receive Vue file

```
export default {
  mounted() {
    Echo.private("notification-" + window.Laravel.user).listen(
      "NotificationEvent",
      e => {
        console.log("there");
      }
    );
  }
};
```

[joining to private channel is okay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJApH.png)
but I cant receive any message from laravel event

```
Route::get('test-broadcast', function () {
    $user = \App\User::findOrFail(1);
    broadcast(new NotificationEvent($user));
});

[2019-02-22 10:46:28] local.INFO: Broadcasting [App\Events\PrivateNotificationProcedure] on channels [private-notification-procedure-1] with payload:
{
    "socket": null
}
```

Im not sure what is wrong.

Thanks lots

Comment: Did you get any solutions ?

Answer (score 0):

run command `php artisan config:clear`
It worked for me